# Documentum - Can child record be deleted without deleting the record in the relation

Tags: dql, documentum

Hello I am completely newbie in Documentum but using DQL for some data extraction purpose.

In dm_relation I have a relation which contains parent_id & child_id which are r_object_ids of 2 types(tables for me)

I am facing a problem. It would be clear if you can tell me that can a record exist in the relation even if the record is deleted in the child table(type)?

I hope I am clear. Also I suppose for now that a record cannot exist in the relation if parent record is deleted (which contains the parent_id).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the properties of the relation.  A similar question has been asked here: https://community.emc.com/message/591116#591116